# passing string argument to mysql

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm trying to parse a value from argument using argparse. Which works fine when I test my conditionals with "print". The error happens when I now add the values to my sql code. Pardon my not so pretty sql query, it's the only way I could get the data that I need.

**Error message:** TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple

```
import mysqldb
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-m','--machine', nargs=1, help="Machine Hostname", action="store")
args = parser.parse_args()

query = (""" select ifname, usname, mtdesc, lobuilding Location from 
interface left join machine on ifmcid=mcid
left join machine_type on mcmtid=mtid left join user on mcusid=usid left join location on mcloid=loid
WHERE mccurrentosid = 32 AND ifname = %s """, (args.machine,))
cur.execute(query )
for row in cur.fetchall():
print row
```

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Comment: TypeError: must be string or read-only buffer, not tuple

Comment: So, there is your answer as well - pass the `args.machine` argument as a plain argument, no encapsulated inside a tuple, as would be needed with string formatting using the `%` operator.

Comment: sorry, can you give an example to your suggestion? Very new to python here. thanks,

Comment: Nonetheless, just check the answer by @alexe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query parameters should be passed into `execute()`:

```
query = """
    select 
        ifname, usname, mtdesc, lobuilding
    from 
        interface 
        left join 
            machine 
        on 
            ifmcid=mcid
        left join 
            machine_type 
        on 
            mcmtid=mtid 
        left join 
            user 
        on 
            mcusid=usid 
        left join 
            location 
        on  
            mcloid=loid
     WHERE 
         mccurrentosid = 32 AND 
         ifname = %s
"""
cur.execute(query, (args.machine,) )
```

Comment: I'm getting a different error now: _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 23")

Comment: @gratchie note that FIXME I've put into the query - should there be a comma between `lobuilding` and `Location`?

Comment: I can actually remove 'location'. Here's my current sql:              query = """ select ifname, usname, mtdesc, lobuilding from interface left join machine on ifmcid=mcid
                     left join machine_type on mcmtid=mtid left join user on mcusid=usid left join location on mcloid=loid
                     WHERE mccurrentosid = 32 AND ifname = %s """
             cur.execute(query, (args.machine,))
             for row in cur.fetchall():
                print row

Answer (score 0):

After trying out different permutations, finally got a working code. I had to remove the ',' in args.machine. Maybe the 'left join' statements doesn't need it anymore.

```
cur.execute(query, (args.machine))
```

Thanks for the help @alecxe